# Identify JavaScript synchronous execution block

Tags: javascript, browser

Can't find any discussion around that. In JavaScript, is there a way to detect that I'm running different functions in the same execution block or that I have already executed my function in the current execution block?

Basically I need to optimize some browser code by avoiding it to run twice in the same synchronous block. For now I'm doing like this:

```
var isSaved = false;
function saveUIState() {
    if(isSaved === true) {
        return;
    }

    // Some heavy DOM processing
    ...

    isSaved = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Reset this flag in another execution block
        isSaved = false;
    }, 0);
}
```

But I'm not guaranteed that my flag is reset before the next execution block.

Although node's `process.nextTick` would be more appropriate, I'm more looking for something like a way to identify an execution block:

```
var lastExecutionBlockID;
function saveUIState() {
    if(lastExecutionBlockID === executionBlockID) {
        return;
    }
    lastExecutionBlockID = executionBlockID;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to research the mediator pattern, I think that will help you in this situation. To subscribe to calls and register events.
[Mediator.js](http://thejacklawson.com/Mediator.js/)
[Mediator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern)